# How to close drawer first then call onBackPressed?

Tags: java, android, drawerlayout

I have an activity with drawer layout.

I want to check if the drawer is closed or not then call `onBackPressed`. If the drawer is open it should close first then `onBackPressed` should get called.

I tried to do like this using addDrawerListener

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setUpUI();

        listeners(
    }

    public void setUpUI() {
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        //Initializing NavigationView
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    }

    public void listeners() 
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                onBackPressed();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() 
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.END);
        if (!mBackPressCancelled) {
            if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

With this drawer gets close half an app gets closed. I want to close the drawer the call onBaackPressed.

How can I do this? Please help. Thank you.

Comment: post your error logcat

Comment: I am not getting any error.@RahulKhurana

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check if drawer is closed or not with

`if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END)) {
  //drawer is open
}else{
     super.onBackPressed();
}`

Comment: this just closes the drawer onBackPressed dose not get called after closing the drawer.

Comment: you can when drawer is open call drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.END);

Comment: I did this. but it only closes drawer onBackPressed

Answer (score 1):

This will be your code:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END)) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END)   
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: this just closes the drawer onBackPressed dose not get called after closing the drawer.

Comment: On first back pressed it will close the drawer. then the second time app goes to back.

Comment: You have to pass GravityComapt.START both times.